# gradle android app build: create a dynamic archicesBaseName with groovy inline function

Tags: gradle, groovy

In my android build.gradle file I want to set the `archivesBaseName` to a dynamic string.
I am struggling to get it to work

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.app"
    versionCode 11
    versionName "1.1.0"
  } 
  
  setProperty("archivesBaseName", {
    def date = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd")
    return $defaultConfig.applicationId + "-" + $defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + $defaultConfig.versionCode + "-" + date
  })
}
```

It's outputting the name of the function closure not the return value of the function. I also tried:

```
setProperty("archivesBaseName", { defaultConfig ->
    def date = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd")
    return defaultConfig.applicationId + "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + defaultConfig.versionCode + "-" + date
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by not using a function at all but I'd still like to know how it could be achieved using a function.

```
setProperty("archivesBaseName", defaultConfig.applicationId + "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "." + defaultConfig.versionCode + "-" + new Date().format("yyyyMMdd-HHmm"))
```